# Bokeh plots requiring bokeh-server and a web server

Tags: python, bokeh

In Bokeh, the [`embed` examples](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed) in the repository (e.g. [`animated.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/animated.py)) require, not only the `bokeh-server` running, but also an actual web server running (e.g. started with `python -m http.server` in Python 3).

Most of the other examples do **not** require a web server running. Why are the `embed` examples different? Why do they require a web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "embed" examples are specifically for demonstrating configuration/usage when you *want* to serve bokeh plots from a web-app.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I was able to run `animated.py` from `plotting/server` without using a web server, so that explains it perfectly.